# Zend Framework - Redirecting to IndexController in different module

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules

All,

I have the following project setup in Zend's mvc Framework. Upon accessing the application, I want the user to redirect to "mobile" module instead of going to IndexController in "default" module. How do I do that?

```
-billingsystem
-application
    -configs
        application.ini
    -layouts
        -scripts
            layout.phtml
    -modules
        -default
            -controllers
                IndexController.php
            -models
            -views
            Bootstrap.php
        -mobile
            -controllers
                IndexController.php
            -models
            -views
            Bootstrap.php
Bootstrap.php
-documentation
-include
-library
-logs
-public
    -design
        -css
        -images
        -js
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

My index.php has the following code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';


$application = new Zend_Application(
  APPLICATION_ENV,
  APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two options :

1- set `mobile` as default module for your application by editing your application.ini file 
`resources.frontController.defaultModule = "mobile"`

2- you can create a plugin that intercept every request and forward to the same controller and action but to the mobile module

```
class Name_Controller_Plugin_mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

                $module = $request->getModuleName();
                $controller = $request->getControllerName();
                $action = $request->getActionName();
                if($module !== "mobile" || $module !== "error"){
                  return $request->setModuleName("mobile")->setControllerName("$controller")
                    ->setActionName("$action")->setDispatched(true);

                 }else{
                   return ;
                 }
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add the error controller to the if clause so you don't end up with mysterious loop when your application throws an error , and that is it

Answer (score 3):

From within a controller you you can use

```
 _forward(string $action, 
          string $controller = null, 
          string $module = null, 
          array $params = null)
```

For example:

```
$this-_forward("index", "index", "mobile");
```

This would go to the index action, index controller of the mobile module, you can also use `null`:

```
$this-_forward(null, null, "mobile");
```

Passing `null` will use the current action and controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there no way to do this globally like in index.php , instead of changing each controller?

Comment: Do it in a `Zend_Controller_Plugin` so that it is done before the dispatcher kicks in